# Get a single row from a database every second?

Tags: c#, database

I have a table with a single column, which has 1000+ rows.

I want to retrieve each row and show it in a label every second.
Thus the first value will be shown in the first second and so on.

The table name is `Numbers`, the column name is `Pules`, the datatype is `int`.

Some example values are `22`, `78`, `71`, `31`, `66` and `50`.

Comment: Use a timer and a method that selects one record from the table. If you use sql-server you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to select always a different record. Store the last row's number in a field and increase it every time the timer elapsed.

Comment: in the table there are numbers like 48,23,99,33,78 , i want it to show on the label each of these number for each second

Comment: Whoever upvoted a question please consider editing it so it clearly shows what exact problem is - reading from DB, setting up method to "run every second", something else. I'd imagine someone already asked some of the questions, so would be nice to add problems with existing implementations too.

Comment: i dont know why people are downvoting?

Comment: i know the last one was yours, its unfair

Comment: i wish i could help this guy, but you guys  Alexei Levenkov, stuartd, Jeff Bridgman, Piyush, showdev dont get it because you dont want to help i

Comment: as you want brother, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easyest way would be using a timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Tick += () => (label.Text = /*database grep*/);
t.Start();
```

**EDIT:**

You could also consider to use this version.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
int i = 0;
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Tick += t_Tick; 
t.Start();
```

And a seperate `t_Tick`.

```
private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = /*database grep using i*/;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: what about sql query ?

Comment: could you help some more

Comment: For this you might have provided some sample code or names,, but so I'm unable to help you further.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409839/reading-dataset or try google'in

Comment: up to know you have contributed a great help i like more if you could

Comment: As I never even had something to do with `SQL` or even `Databases` I'm sorry that I can't help furthermore. Anyway, if it helped you please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For performance purposes, you can retrieve a large amount of results from the database in a dataset and display the results one by one, with a Timer. It's still better to do one time a query, rather than one query each second.