# C# Get String From Data set Exception

Tags: c#, string, datatable, dataset

I searched already & it isn't the issue to read Dataset , The issue is i done same but it is not working

I Am trying to get complete name from Datasset, when i try following

```
String Receiver_name = rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][First_Name].ToString() + " " + rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][Last_Name].ToString();
```

it gives `ArgumentNullException was unHandeled` With sub Message of 'name' argument cannot be null.

so I searched over internet & changed Code to

```
String Receiver_name = rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][“First_Nameˮ].ToString() + “ ˮ + rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][“Last_Nameˮ].ToString();
```

now it gives `“First_Nameˮ Doesn't exist in content`

I tried get it working by following , It doesn't seems any difference (  in above and below code) to me in any kind but it works perfectly

**My question is Why this work while above doesn't worked, And why above code doesn't work**

```
String Receiver_name = rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["First_Name"].ToString();
Receiver_Name+= " " + rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
```

Comment: you can see..this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6412967/1660178 can help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading DataSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409839/reading-dataset)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, because he knows how to access the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `“First_Nameˮ` is treated as a variable name and not as a quoted string, as the quotes are not "normal" double quotes, but typographical left/right quotes, so they are threated as unicode signs.

Change them to normal double quotes.

```
String Receiver_name = rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["First_Name"].ToString() + " " + rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
```

So: Be careful when copy&pasting from the internet - make sure the quotes are actually recognised as quotes and check the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Your Code is 100% Correct Except you `doesn't use Double Quotes`
might be due to you copied from web

actually you are using `Left Double quotes & Right Double quotes` , Their Hexadecimal values doesn't match with simple quotes

```
Character name             Symbol  Decimal-Val   Hax-Val

left double quotation mark   “      8220         201C
right double quotation mark  ”      8221         201D
double quotes                "      34           22
```

In Compiler **left double quotation mark & Right double quotation mark Considered to be part of name** , Not considered as quotation Mark, That's why you getting error

Following will work fine for you

```
 Receiver_name = rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["First_Name"].ToString() + " " + rec_Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Last_Name"].ToString();
```